# split a huge single line json into separate files

Tags: json, bash, shell, split, terminal

I've got a huge (>4GB) JSON file where all the information is written in one single line. Unfortunately, my scripts can't work with such a huge file and I wasn't able to split it into multiple lines. Every script or program I've used was crashing because of limited memory.

Can you help me splitting a json file into several files => for example with a bash command?

Comment: That's just too difficult to achieve because you don't know where an object ends, ect ... It only works if the root object consists of one key whose value is an array of objects. If not, then ... generate the file by dividing it to multiple files first (or use a delimiter, not advisable IMHO). Don't make it as one file.

Comment: I've got the file from a developer, who isn't willing to make an ordinary json file with multiple lines, so that doesn't help.

Comment: [json_reformat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man1/json_reformat.1.html) will put the input back on multiple lines.

Comment: You can try to convert it to SQLite database using sqlitebiter but you probably need to have array of objects http://sqlitebiter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/usage/file/

Comment: is it one big object or array?  show the very beginning and end of the file

Comment: Please specify what functions your scripts that can't work with large files are meant to perform.

Comment: I'm using http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/index.php?lang=en to view and reformat JSON files.